# abstract class with abstract fields and subclassing without casting

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I created an abstract base class.  It contains an object which should be extended by any subclasses:

```
public abstract class AbstractParent {
    protected AbstractObject subMePlz;
    // ... some fields that all subclasses need
    public AbstractParent() {
        this.subMePlz = createThisInYourExtendedClass();

    }

    public abstract AbstractObject createThisInYourExtendedClass();
}
```

the abstractObject:

```
public abstract class AbstractObject {
   // ... some fields/methods that all subclasses need 
}
```

What I want is to be able to use the extended field in the extended class without casting:

```
public class ExtendParent extends AbstractParent {
     // .. some unique fields
     public ExtendParent(){
       super();
     }


   public ConcreteObject createThisInYourExtendedClass(){
        return new ConcreteObject();
   }

   // what I want to do - no cast
   public void doSomethingWithSubMePlzWithoutCastingIt() {
        System.out.println(this.subMePlz);  
   }

   // what I end up doing - gotta cast
   public void doSomethingWithSubMePlzWithoutCastingIt() {
        System.out.println((ConcreteObject)this.subMePlz);  
   }
}
```

Would needing a comparator change how I should implement this? - I'm thinking a generic comparator for a list of the AbstractObjects that could be used by its subclasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make it generic:

```
public abstract class AbstractParent<T extends AbstractObject> {
    protected T subMePlz;
    // ... some fields that all subclasses need
    public AbstractParent() {
        this.subMePlz = createThisInYourExtendedClass();

    }

    public abstract T createThisInYourExtendedClass();
} 

public class ExtendParent extends AbstractParent<ConcreteObject> {
    ...
}
```

Note that calling non-private methods within a constructor is *usually* a bad idea - the subclass won't have been fully initialized yet, which can make it difficult to reason about how much you can really rely on.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Abandon the project to declare the field in the superclass.  Instead, add an internal abstract "getter" method to your superclass -- basically, `AbstractParent` should have a method `abstract AbstractObject getSubMePlz()`.
2. Use generics to set the type of `subMePlz` in your subclass: define `AbstractParent<T>` to have a `T` for its `subMePlz` field.

Personally, I frequently find option 1 to be very pleasantly extensible -- for example, you can have another subclass that narrows the `getSubMePlz()` return type without yet declaring it, which can be advantageous.

Comment: for option 1 would that be abstract T getSubMePlz()?

Comment: Option 1 doesn't involve any generics at all, though I suppose you could combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this -

```
     super.subMePlz
```

instead of this -

```
    (ConcreteObject)this.subMePlz
```

That way, you won't need a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You just could save a copy of the object in the subclass but with the correct class.

```
public class ExtendParent extends AbstractParent {
  ConcreteObject concreteObject;

  public AbstractObject createThisInYourExtendedClass(){
    ConcreteObject concreteObject = new ConcreteObject();
    return concreteObject;
  }
  public void doSomethingWithSubMePlzWithoutCastingIt() {
    System.out.println(concreteObject);  
  }

  ...
```